# How to open a form in editable mode

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_daytime = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=75)
    password =  models.CharField(max_length=75)
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    """"""
    registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST)      
    if registerform.is_valid() and createprofileform.is_valid():                
        result = registerform.save(commit=False)
        result.set_password(request.POST['password'])                                   
        result.save()
        member.user_id = user.id
        member.member_id = result.id
        member.save()                                        
        member_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=result.id)
        createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=member_profile)
                createprofileform.save()   
    return render(request,'profile.html',{'createprofileform':createprofileform,'registerform':registerform})
```

view  to save the data to database.

template

```
<tr>
   <td>First name:</td><td>{{registerform.first_name}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Last name:</td><td>{{registerform.last_name}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Daytime phone:</td><td>{{createprofile.phone_daytime}} </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Email:</td><td>{{registerform.email}} </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Password</td><td>{{registerform.password}} </td>
 </tr>
```

The saved name and email id are displayed in template like this,

```
  <td> <input type="submit" name="delete" value="{{list.0.id}}" class="delete_reporter" /></span>
<a href="{{list.0.id}}">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</a></td>
 <td> {{list.0.email}} {{list.1.phone_daytime}} {{list.1.phone_mobile}}</td>
```

In template,if i click `<a href="{{list.0.id}}">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</a>` the form should open in editable mode,so that if i want to make changes i can change and save it again.How to do this in django.I am passing the id in `<a>` tag.

Comment: What is the point of having readonly forms? Forms are always editable with very rare exceptions. You should read on modelforms to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: I want to open it in same page in editable mode,I am not using different html for edit,doing both in same method,where initially i am adding data to form.How to frame url and how to pass the id to view.

Comment: I tried with form instance,i am confused with providing id in urls and views,I am getting page not found error(404)

Comment: What i am asking is,the above view code is for inserting the data in database.A row of data is added in database.In template the inserted data are viewed as given in question,and if i click this link <a href="{{list.0.id}}">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</a> from template,the data whatever i added are views in the same form field in editable mode,so that i can add and update the data. You can guess this as when you click edit link in SO question or answer,the same question or answer open in editable mode,this is what i am looking for.can you please guide me how to do

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to have some kind of data, that can be edited and saved.
You can achive this with the help of forms. Here's an example:

Define your form:

```
class BasicForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    age = forms.IntegerField()
```

Then, in your views define your logic and provide initial data for your form:

```
def update_view(request):
    initial_data = {'name': 'John', 'age': 25}
    form = BasicForm(initial_data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
          form = BasicForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              #  Do something with passed data, for example update existing model.
              pass

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

If you want to update your models in database you can provide initial data like this:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

model = Model.objects.get(name='John')
initial_data = model_to_dict(model, exclude=['field_name'])

form = BasicForm(initial_data)

if request.method == 'POST':
      form = BasicForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          #  Update your "John" model
          model.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
          model.age = form.cleaned_data['age']
          model.save()
```

Take a look into [django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/).

Comment: What i am asking is,the above view code is for inserting the data in database.A row of data is added in database.In template the inserted data are viewed as given in question,and if i click  this link <a href="{{list.0.id}}">{{list.0.first_name|title}} {{list.0.last_name}}</a> from template,the data whatever i added are views in the same form field in editable mode,so that i can add and update the data.This is what i required,can you please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: You can guess this as when you click edit link in SO question or answer,the same question or answer open in editable mode,this is what i am looking for